# Fastest way to uniquify a list of objects based on object attribute

Tags: python, list, unique

Im currently uniquifying a list of objects based on their name attribute by creating a dict of objects with the name value as the dict key like this:

```
obj_dict = dict()

for obj in obj_list:
    if not obj.name in obj_dict:
        obj_dict[obj.name] = obj

new_obj_list = obj_dict.items()
```

And I was wondering if there was a quicker or more pythonic way to do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If two objects with the same name should always considered identical you could implement `__eq__` and `__hash__` accordingly. Then your solution would be as easy as storing all your objects in a `set()`:

```
new_obj_list = list(set(obj_list))
```

Converting the list back to a set is probably not even necessary since the order is lost anyway so unless you need to do something with it that only works with a list but not with a set just keep using the set.

Comment: Exactly my idea, but typing answers on an iPad is slow :)

Answer (score 1):

And if you need ordering:

```
oset = set()
new_obj_list = []
for o in obj_list:
    if o not in oset:
        oset.add(o)
        new_obj_list.append(o)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also go the set approach but then figured you want to be able to look-up by name I guess..., but here's another approach that doesn't require amending the class... (albeit a bit more expensive)... Note that you could add further sort parameters to `sorted` to order by other priorities (such as age, or gender etc...)

```
from operator import attrgetter
from itetools import groupby
unique_by_name = {key: next(item) for key, item in groupby(attrgetter('name'), sorted(obj_list, key=attrgetter('name')))}
```

There's a unique last seen recipe in itertools too.

Otherwise for different ordering requirements, put them as different class methods, (or one called 'sort' that takes a known order and calls an internal function)...